# How to easily append row to a table with xlwings and pandas?

Tags: pandas, xlwings

How to easily append row to a table with xlwings and pandas ?

We cannot clean the previous rows and we just want to add few row at the bottom of the table

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

very simple using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.ExcelFile(xl_path).parse(sheet_name).append(iterable, ignore_index=True)
```

where iterable can be a list or a dict where the keys are the column names (or index).
Note that this function returns a new DataFrame with the new row appended.